# JLS-8 Classes in Java Interfaces can only be on top most class

Tags: java

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3 defines that interfaces can only be defined on top most classes, while it allows abstract classes to be defined even within static methods. Why can't we define an interface inside a method, the same way we can define classes or abstract classes and final static variable constants?

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class ThisWorks {
        }

        abstract class ThisAlsoWorks {
            public static final String key = "value";
        }

        interface ThisDoesntWork {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Answer: Because SPEC says so! Counter-question: Why should someone want/need that?